# hackerrank xor in arrays

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, xor

I am trying to solve [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sansa-and-xor) problem on hackerrank and it took me a while to get to the trick.

The trick lies in property of xor and the number of times a number appears in a subset of array where a **subset is contiguous one (kindly note)**.

So if we have 1,2,3 the subsets will be:

```
1
1,2
1,2,3
2
2,3
3
```

The number of times a value at index i appears in these subsets is `(n-i)*(i+1)` as it can be seen that 1 appears (3-0)*(0+1) = 3 times. *n* is the length of the array.

Second trick is `XOR` of a number is 0 with itself if we take  that number even number of times and if it appears odd number of times the answer is the number itself, also the important thing to note is `XOR` operation is associative.

The problem asks us to xor the subsets and then take `XOR` of each resultant value.

So rather than brute force approach, I counted the number of times each number appears in array and checked out whether it occurs even number of times or odd number of times but 8 testcases passed and 4 failed. The test case are too long to debug or dry run.

My question is why 4 testcase failed. Here is the Java code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;    
public class J {       
    static int []arr=new int[100000];
    static int an;
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {

        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        int t,i,j,n;String []s;            
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        t=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());            
        int []ans=new int[t];
        for(i=0;i<t;++i)
        {
         n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());             
         s=br.readLine().split(" ");
         j=0;         an=0;
         for(String str:s)
          arr[j++]=Integer.parseInt(str);
         for(j=0;j<n;++j)
         {                    
             if(((j+1)*(n-j))%2==1)
              an=an^arr[j];         
         }
         ans[i]=an;
        }
        for(i=0;i<t;++i)
         System.out.println(ans[i]);    
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is overflow in

```
(j+1)*(n-j)
```

The product may be `~10^10` cause the total size of array is up to `10^5`.

So you need to calculate this product using `long`.

I tested your code with this dummy change:

```
long a = j + 1;
long b = (n - j);

if((a*b)%2==1) {
    an=an^arr[j]; 
}
```

And program passed all tests successfully.